# Object literal's property implicitly has an 'any[]' type - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded angular 2 to stable version & suddenly I started getting this error in webpack watcher `Object literal's property 'avatars' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.` Here is the line which is giving that error: `private selectedContact = {'jcf': {'avatars': [], 'fullname': ''}, meta: []};` Its giving same error for `meta`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the new typescript update come new rules and flags. One of these flags is the `noImplicitAny` flag. This makes sure you don't initialise a variable like this:

```
let avatars = [];
```

You can either change your `tsconfig.json` to no longer mark this as an error by using:

```
{
    noImplicitAny: false
}
```

or you can create an interface/class which represents your `selectedContact`

```
export interface Contact {
    jcf: ContactDetail;
    meta: any[];
}
```

And another interface:

```
export interface ContactDetail {
    avatars: any[];
    fullname: string;
}
```

Now you can assign a Contact interface to your selectedContact property:

```
private selectedContact: Contact = {...};
```

Or, which is not very nice, you can explicitly assign it to `any[]`:

```
let avatars: any[] = [];
```

Comment: So the what's the ideal way? I think creating interfaces would be better, this way my model will have proper type of data. Right?

Comment: It will let TypeScript assure you that before compilation the right type of data will be in your model yes. But if you use `instanceof Contact` it will still return false. You will need to create and instantiate a class for that